# How to update DB in singleton instance?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, singleton, entity-framework-core

My app uses a singleton pattern for a handler class instance. It is responsible for handling some events:

```
public class MyHandler
{
    public void HandlerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //want to update DB here
    }
}
```

It is possibly MyHandler will need to start interaction with DB. So can I do it? There is my vision:

1. Just tough attach `DbContext` as singleton at `MyHandler`. Obviously it's a bad idea.
2. Use ASP.Net Core DI features and send `DbContext` to `MyHandler`, but as an instance "one per request". I think in my case (`MyHandler` is singleton) this is similar to 1
3. Do it through `using` operator, i.e. as atomic transaction, for e.g. `using(var context = new XDbContext()) {...}` As for me it's a good approach, but DbContext of Entity Framework Core implementation needs `DbContextOptions` as argument of its constructor. If I declare parameterless constructor for XDbContext then it throws an exception.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you renew the instance in every request? Like for example have a `DbContext` property in your `MyHandler` class and in it's get renew your instance of `XDbContext` you don't need to worry about previous instances since they'll be collected via GC.

Comment: @Emad in my case `HandlerEvent` processes messages which arrives from azure service bus, i.e. it does not depend on http-requests

Comment: My point is still valid though the answer of Egorikas does the same thing using the factory pattern. You can have the entire code of the factory create in get method of my DbContext property.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen an ef core tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext) and as I understood, `DbContextOptions` - is just an object with configuration parameters inside it. If I had same problem, I would use the third way (with using), but would create a helper for injecting parameters or using a factory for this. I found an example of factory in the tutorial

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;

namespace MyProject
{
   public class BloggingContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<BloggingContext>
   {
       public BloggingContext Create()
       {
          var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>();
          optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=./blog.db");

          return new BloggingContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
       }
   }
}
```

Example of using:

```
public class MyHandler
{
   public void HandlerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // Or make 'Create' method static
       using(var context = new BloggingContextFactory().Create())
       {
                 . . . 
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can such approach undermine main DB-configurations which were implemented in OnModelCreating method? Or this constructor is not matter for OnModelCreating-configs?

Comment: @Mergasov As I know, new EF core is being written in the way like ASP.NET core. Which means that we don't have web.config and store our properties  in another file (appsettings.json for example), so I suppose that this approach can undermine main DB-configurations, but I'm not sure. Watch https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings and ASP.NET Core section